# Package 'effects': predictorEffects function customising the y axis with overprinting

Tags: data-visualization, effects

I have this predictorEffects finction, which results in overprinting of the labels on the y-axis, however, I have tried many things and they don't seem to be working. Here's the code I used:

`pretty <- predictorEffects(newbinomial15)
plot(predictorEffects(newbinomial15,y=list(rotate=30)))
r <- plot(pretty,axes=list(y=list(rug=FALSE, rotate=30), lattice = list(layout=c(3,1))))`

[image: Plot output]

Any advice would be amazing! I really need to fix the labels!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to try recreating these same plots using the **ggeffects** package.  Here is a quick example of how you would do this for a binary logistic regression model without interactions among its predictors:

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)

m <- glm(am ~ wt + cyl, family = binomial(link="logit"), data = mtcars)

library(ggeffects) 

g1 <- ggpredict(m, terms = "wt")
g2 <- ggpredict(m, terms = "cyl")

g1
g2

p1 <- plot(g1)
p2 <- plot(g2)

library(cowplot)

plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

The plots p1 and p2 can be customized further quite easily - see for example the **ggeasy** easy package, which makes customization of ggplots a breeze (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeasy/vignettes/shortcuts.html).

For models with interaction terms, refer to the package vignette:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/ggeffects.html